# Decorating a function to create a class that splits keyword and positional arguments into two other methods

Tags: python, python-decorators, inspect

I have an abstract class that `@abstractmethods` its `__init__` and `__call__`. In principle, the class definition is like this:

```
class Base(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, **params):
        pass

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __call__(self, *input):
        pass
```

I want to create a decorator that converts a function's keyword arguments into arguments into `__init__` and positional arguments into `__call__`: so if

```
def func(a, b, *args, k=1, g=2, **kwargs):
    pass # it does something
```

then I would like to wrap my func in a decorator that will output like along the lines of

```py
class Func(Base):
    def __init__(self, k=1, g=2, **kwargs):
        inspected_kwargs = ... # arguments of init in dictionary form
        for argname, val in inspected_kwargs.items():
             setattr(self, argname, val)

    def __call__(self, a, b, *args):
        inspected_args = ... # arguments of call in tuple form
        return func(*inspected_args, **self.__dict__)
```

I had a few attempts using `inspect` but I'm not sure how to inject the parameters from `inspect.Signature` object back to create a function. Also, I had some trouble because when local methods are added to a class that is inner to a function with simple attribute setting, the local functions are no longer in scope when the class is returned.

The question is: how to create a class inside a function whose methods are defined based on the signature of the function's input callable?

@edit
To provide more details on the idea:

```py
def decorator(function):
    class Inner(Base):
        pass
    # non-existent functions ahead, just to convey the idea
    # the exact way to do this is exactly the matter of this question
    sig = inspect.get_signature(function)
    init = create_from_signature(signature=sig.keyword_arguments(),
body="for name, val in sig.keyword_arguments():\nsetattr(self, name, val)")
    call = create_from_signature(signature=sig.positional(),
body="return partial(func, **self.__dict__)")
    Inner.__init__ = init
    Inner.__call__ = call
    # it would be nice if Inner class name would also depend on
    # func name:
    setattr(Inner, __name__, "_".join(function.__name__, "decorated"))
    return Inner

def users_function(a, b, k=5):
    # user's code; does whatever, for me it's a black box
    return a * b / k
```

Expected behaviour:

```
decorator(users_function)(k=10)(1, 2) == users_function(1, 2, k=10)
```

Why do I want to do this? Because then one can call the methods of `Base` on the outputted object, for which knowledge of only keyword arguments would be required:

```
my_obj = decorator(users_function)(k=10)
my_obj.basemethod() # basemethod is implementd in Base class
```

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand, can you clarify your last point. Also, where exactly are you running into an issue? Thanks.

Comment: I just have no idea how to create a function that will match a signature from signature object. Later adding this method to the class is another issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand exactly what your problem is so let's start with this example:

```
def decorator(function):

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        print(' [decorator] Printing before function [' + function.__name__ + '] execution')

        result = function(*args, **kwargs)

        print(' [decorator] Found args: ' + str(args))
        print(' [decorator] Found kwargs: ' + str(kwargs))

        print(' [decorator] Printing after function [' + function.__name__ + '] execution')

        return result

    return wrapper


@decorator
def MyFunction(*args, **kwargs):

    print('[MyFunction] Received args:' + str(args))
    print('[MyFunction] Received kwargs:' + str(kwargs))


MyFunction(1, 2, kwarg1=3, kwarg2=2)
```

It will result in:

```
 [decorator] Printing before function [MyFunction] execution
[MyFunction] Received args:(1, 2)
[MyFunction] Received kwargs:{'kwarg1': 3, 'kwarg2': 2}
 [decorator] Found args: (1, 2)
 [decorator] Found kwargs: {'kwarg1': 3, 'kwarg2': 2}
 [decorator] Printing after function [MyFunction] execution
```

Where do you need to take your problem from here?